# Interdependent function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```py
def rabbit(t):

    num = r0*(e**(rb*t))+ fox(t-1)*0.3

    return num

def fox(t):

    num = f0*(e**(rf*t))+ rabbit(t-1)*0.15

    return num
```

So I am trying to graph the above 2 functions in matplotlib
As you can see both functions are dependent on one another
rabbit gets eaten by fox and if fox have more rabbit to eat it with grow faster

Problem is, this will throw a recursion depth error(clearly)

`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

However if I add basecase and recursive case

```py
def rabbit(t):

    if(t>0):
        num = r0*(e**(rb*t))+ fox(t-1)*0.3
    else:
        num = r0
    return num

def fox(t):

    if(t>0):    
        num = f0*(e**(rf*t))+ rabbit(t-1)*0.15
    else:
        num = f0
    return num
```

to this I get this error

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: I think you're passing `t` as numpy array instead of int

Comment: How are you calling the functions? Currently, there is no error in the code presented. Consider a MRE.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Good day to you.  The function you provided works as long as you define the variables and call it on a number. As an example this works just fine on my machine:

```
r0 = 1
rb = 1
f0 = 1
rf = 3
e = 2.818
def rabbit(t):
    if(t>0):
        num = r0*(e**(rb*t))+ fox(t-1)*0.3
    else:
        num = r0
    return num

def fox(t):
    if(t>0):    
        num = f0*(e**(rf*t))+ rabbit(t-1)*0.15
    else:
        num = f0
    return num
print(rabbit(30),fox(30))
```

The error message you get looks like a numpy error message and I think that you try to pass t as a numpy array. This is causing an issue because if(t>0) become ambiguous... t contains multiple elements ! If your intention is to plot rabbit and fox over an interval (let's say from -10 to 10) then you could do this instead using a list comprehension (you need to import matplotlib.pyplot as plt and numpy as np):

```
x = np.linspace(-10,10,1000)
rabbit_values = np.array([rabbit(t) for t in x])
fox_values = np.array([fox(t) for t in x])
plt.plot(x,fox_values, label='fox')
plt.plot(x,rabbit_values,label='rabbit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Does it help ?